# Logical operations on return

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, asp.net-3.5

I'm trying to apply my ActionScript knowledge to C# and I've been wondering if it's possible to make this kinds of return statements:

```
return myObject ||= new Object();
```

Of course I can use a longer version like:

```
if (!myObject)
myObject = new Object();
return myObject;
```

and it works fine, but I just want to be able to obfuscate my code and make it a little shorter.

I figured since it's all ECMAScript, it should work, but it doesn't. Could anyone point out if it's possible to use logical operators to mimic if-else instead of usual if-then-else statements?

The .NET version is 3.5 (Unity3d engine)

Comment: If you vote down, please explain why, so the post could be improved. I see nothing wrong with my post.

Comment: Your longer version does not work because in .NET, an object cannot be implicitely converted to bool (and conditions are required to be booleans)

Comment: 1) In Unity3d it works just fine
2) Object() in this case is just an instance of some Class, for all you care I could call it T.

Comment: by "obfuscating your code" do you mean - make it harder to understand?! never make that your goal. there are special tools for obfuscating *the compiled code* that allow you to protect your intelectual property (besides, the "??" operator will be compiled to the if-else statement)

Comment: @lisp I'm not stating everybody should use that, I just wanted to know if I can do that. It could be useful!

Comment: @CreativeMagic the "??" operator *does* make the code much clearer and i do advise you to use it whenever suitable. just never introduce modifications to code that only *make it harder to understand*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is the coalesce operator in C# that does almost exactly this.

```
 return myObject ?? new Object();
```

**EDIT**: This does not change the variable `myObject`. If you want to do this as well, you can simply write

```
 return myObject = myObject ?? new Object();
```

because an assignment in C# is also an expression that returns the value that has been assigned.

Comment: oh, wow I never thought it would be so close, right under my nose, just a different syntax. Thanks! I would never have guessed to use "??"

Comment: @CreativeMagic why would you guess? you have to learn the language syntax.

Comment: Sometimes certain symbols "make sense", either from cultural cross-pollination or synesthesia.  It's also fun to guess.

Comment: @lisp - do you really learn every single operator, keyword, corner case and what not, before you write a single line of code in a new language?

Comment: @lisp it does not happen in a day. I do learn, but you can't really expect me not to code and try things for, let's say, two years until I know ALL the syntax :)

Comment: @corak - of course you learn gradually, by asking this kind of questions for examle. I just can't imagine *guessing* syntax. you use what you know - the if-else statement was perfectly fine and clear. jus as it's perfrectly fine to wonder if the code could be shortened and *learn* that

Comment: @lisp - well, I *learned* the `+` and `-` operators. Then I *learned* about `+=` so I *guessed* that there is/should be something like `-=` which I'd expect to work analogous. Then I *tried* it and *learned* that my expectations were true. - Now, the OP *learned* that there is something like `||=` in ActionScript and *guessed* that there should be something similar in C#. He *tried* that and *learned* that `||=` doesn't work in C#. Maybe he guessed and tried other symbol combinations but found non that worked. He *never guessed* `??`, but now he *learned* about it. ^_^

Comment: @Corak you've just wrote the story of my life :D

Comment: silly to admit it, but I actually found out that the answer is not really correct since your advice would not modify the myObject, it would always make a new instance of the object, while AS3 version also sets the empty objects value AND return it.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent in C# is

```
return myObject ?? new Object();
```

So it seems like some of the operators are slightly different.

Comment: No, after a new operator, there is always a type, not a variable name.

Comment: @Cheesebaron you've made a typo after "new" it should be "Object()", please edit your answer ;)